# Detecting embedded flash media on a website

Tags: web-scraping

I was wondering if it is possible to detect embedded flash media (as in grabbing the actual media url) on any webpage by just looking at the sourcecode. Some webpages actually include the media url in the 's parameters, but on many webpages the url is hashed or it's not there at all. 
Applications such as Ant Video Downloader seem to have no problem with this and always manage to get the media url for you, but I'm guessing this is done by sniffing packets or by some similar approach. 
Can it be done programatically? And if so, where to start?

Comment: If your web browser is able to detect it then it is possible to do it.

Comment: If it wasn't possible, how would your browser know what to show you?

Comment: @Andrey beat me to it :(

Comment: You actually need to visit the webpage in that case. I'm asking if it can be done by just running a script of some sort.